# cocoapods issue with IBDesingables

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ibdesignable

it's first time for me to develop my own pod and i create a pod with an example to implement the pod, the pod is working great but i wanted that user to be able to init with coding or using Storyboard so i tried to use @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable to be able to change the properties in view the issue i found that error saying that

> file:///Users/belalmedhat/Desktop/SwipeySearch/Example/SwipeySearch/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController (vXZ-lx-hvc): dlopen(SwipeySearch.framework, 0x0001): tried: '/Applications/Xcode Rosetta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/SwipeySearch.framework/SwipeySearch' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode Rosetta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SwipeySearch.framework/SwipeySearch' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode Rosetta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRootSwipeySearch.framework' (no such file), 'SwipeySearch.framework' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Library/Frameworks/SwipeySearch.framework/SwipeySearch' (no such file)

and here is the code for the search view

```
@IBDesignable public class SwipeySearchClass: UIView {

@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak public var searchView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak public var searchButton: UIButton!

@IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        contentView.layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
    }
}
@IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}
@IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        contentView.layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
    }
}

/*
 // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
 // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
 // Drawing code
 }
 */
public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initMe()
    
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initMe()
    
}
public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    initMe()
    
}
public override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    initMe()
}

private func initMe(){
    
    let bundle = Bundle(for: SwipeySearchClass.self)
    let view = UINib(nibName: "SwipeySearchView", bundle: bundle).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    view.frame = self.bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
    
    
}
public func buttonShape(type:SearchShape) {
    searchButton.clipsToBounds = true
    switch type {
    case .circle:
        searchButton.layer.cornerRadius = searchButton.frame.width/2
        break
    case .roundedSquare(let corner):
        searchButton.layer.cornerRadius = corner
        break
    }
    
 }
}

public enum SearchShape {
 case circle
 case roundedSquare(corner:CGFloat)
}
```

[image]